# best way to add an xml element around xml or a row-by-row basis

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012

On SQL Server 2012 (SP1), what's the best way to take data that looks like this:

```
declare @t table (
  id int,
  data xml
)

insert into @t values (1, '<node/>'), (2, '<node/>')

id  data
1   <node />
2   <node />
```

and turn it into

```
id  data
1   <root><node /></root>
2   <root><node /></root>
```

?

Is there a way that's more efficient than just converting it to character data, adding the node start and end tag and then converting it back to xml? I'm dealing with this issue on larger data sets, so this is just a simple example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use simple XQuery to add `<root>` parent in your query result. No back-and-forth conversion between XML and VARCHAR data types involved :

```
SELECT  id, data.query('<root>{.}</root>') AS data
FROM @t
```

Quick test : http://rextester.com/RLZ30365

**Brief explanation :**

- **`{}`** : indicates that texts in between should be treated as XQuery expression instead of literals
- **`.`** : reference to current context node, which in this case is `<node />`

Answer (score 4):

One more approach (but my favorite was har07's answer)

```
declare @t table (
  id int,
  data xml
)

insert into @t values (1, '<node/>'), (2, '<node/>');

SELECT id
      ,(SELECT data AS [*] FOR XML PATH('root'),TYPE)
FROM @t;
```

Comment: Always good to have options. But since you like har07's answer better and it's perfectly cromulent, I'll go with it.

Comment: @jep yeah! options are great! (I had to look up *cromulent*, thx for the new word :-D ).  Is this for Simpsons geeks only or something one could use in every day conversation?)

Comment: _Cromulent_ is a word that can embiggen anyone's vocabulary, Simpsons fan or not.